# Explain This Javascript code for me please

Tags: javascript, arraylist

Am learning  JavaScript.... I would like someone to explain how this code works for me, especially the marked line:

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  let list = null;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list}; //<----- this line
  }
  return list;
}
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]));
```

Comment: Can you add what you understand and what you don't? Because explaining absolutely everything involved (e.g., arrays, loops, lists) could be long.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: Iterates through the array from the and, and for each element creates a new object (typically it would be _head_ and _tail_ fields, but your code uses _value_ and _rest_). The _tail/rest_ is always the object previously created.

Comment: { value: 10, rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: null } } } is the answer when runned on console calling "console.log(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]));". Since the iteration started from the back (right to left), how come 30 not the first value?

Comment: manually (pen and paper) simulate what the loop does, you'll see that list first gets { value: 30, rest: null } and that the result is correct

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, there are no linked lists as is, but the structure can be implemented using an object. In a linked list, each element points to the next, and the last one to null.

[image: A linked list whose nodes contain two fields: an integer value and a link to the next node. The last node is linked to a terminator used to signify the end of the list.]

When using the braces you are defining a Javascript object, whose properties are *value*, and *rest*. In this case the loop begins by taking the last element of the array and creates an object that would simulate an element of the linked list:

```
{ value: 30, rest: null }
```

Then, for the following element, creates another object by linking to the immediately preceding element:

```
{ value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: null } }
```

And finally, create the first item in the list that points to the previous one, resulting in the linked list:

```
{ value: 10, rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: null } } }
```

You can learn more about linked list in Wikipedia [Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) page.

Comment: "*In JavaScript, there are no lists as is, but the structure can be simulated using an object.*" why "simulated"? I'd say *implemented*, as the structure *is* a list. In C, for example, there are also no lists natively, but you'd *implement* a linked list using structs. You don't "emulate" lists, since there isn't a One True List out there. Some languages just have a native implementation of a list (e.g., Java), others don't. Also, the array in JS really behaves like a list, rather than array in other languages, so I'm not entirely comfortable saying that lists simply don't exist.

Comment: What I was trying to refer to with list word was the linked list data structure. I think you'll be more comfortable with the little edition I just made. As for the use of the word simulated instead of implemented you are absolutely right, sorry for my English.

Comment: Indeed you guys are awesome.. i really appreciate. Thanks soooooo much!

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is an ordered collection of data, the collection contains a number of different nodes. So in the above answer you can see four separate nodes, each node contains some amount of data along with a reference to the next node. Together they are referred to as a linked list.

The order of the nodes in a linked list will not randomly change unless we specifically want to change it.

In every linked list there are always two special nodes, the head node and the tail node.

The tail node can be identified by not having any reference to any other node.

Every single node has two discrete parts, it has some data in it which can be absolutely anything we want, it can be a string, a number, an array an object, any JavaScript value. Above you see 12, 99 and 37. The other part of the node is a reference to the next node along the chain.

What is a reference in the JavaScript world?

```
const nodeOne = { data: 123 };

const nodeTwo = { data: 456 };
```

Above are two separate nodes that are not linked at all.

To link them together I have to specifically form a reference between them.
I can do that like so:

```
nodeOne.next = nodeTwo;
```

So now if I want to figure out what the first node in the chain is, it
would definitely be nodeOne because nodeOne contains a reference to nodeTwo.

Now my version of a linked list above is the most simple one you can create. It meets all the rules of a linked list.